# Extended Textbox is behind other elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

It's the first time i am learning WPF with C#. 
So i have a textbox which is extended when i click on a button. The problem is when i extend it,it remains behind my other elements(textboxes etc...)

Here is the xml code for the textbox.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="5" Panel.ZIndex="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="descriptionPanel" Margin="2,0,0,0" Background="White">
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Name="descriptionTextBoxExtended" 
                     Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                     Style="{StaticResource expandedTextBox}"
                     Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, TargetNullValue=''}"                     
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Control}, Path=SecurityLevel2ReadOnly, Mode=OneWay}"
                  />
                    <Button Name="descriptionHide"  Style="{StaticResource MinusButton}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,10,10" Click="descriptionHide_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
```

And here is the C#

```
private void exDescription_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        descriptionPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This is how it looks when i run it before i click the extend button:
[image]

And this is how it looks when i extend the textbox:
[image]

I want all the highlighted components to be behind the textbox.

Comment: I guess you didn't put all elements in the same `Panel` then. Your sample code is pretty useless to be able to reproduce your issue though.

Comment: If you just show overlapping `TextBox` it would still be possible to set focus on comboboxes behind and use arrow keys to change their values, etc. Consider to simply have both: container with edit controls and non-ediatable `TextBlock` inside same parent (e.g. `Grid`) and bind their visibility to show only one at a time. You can start with 2 boolean properties in the view model, which will be set (one to true, another to false) when button command is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give us the code of the other elements beside "descriptionPanel", but as mm8 pointed out, it seems that your elements are not in the same Panel.

Comment: This probably makes more sense as a comment.

Comment: Thank you Fabiobreo and mm8! Sorry if i provided wrong code. Your thought was correct and it worked :)